# matlab neural network toolbox

Tags: c++, matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, matlab-deployment

I used the matlab neural network to train on some data but I want to run this neural network in c++ program,how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ML to generate your feature set (input layer) and then use an open source C++ NN implementation to do training/classification. (E.g., http://takinginitiative.net/2008/04/23/basic-neural-network-tutorial-c-implementation-and-source-code/) If you want to use ML to train and C++ to classify it shouldn't be too difficult to write some additional code to write out the trained network in a way that can be read in by the C++ classifier.

Comment: how I get the weights and the thershold function from the matlab

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Matlab Compiler that generates code you can embed in your C++ application

Comment: this will be a good Idea if the generated code doesn't need th matlab libraries anymore so that I can run the program in other machines doesn't contains matlab

Comment: BTW, how to do that without needing the matlab any more?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Matlab R2013a. If you are still facing with this issue, try to look at this location

```
Matlab\R2013a\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnderivative\+nnMex2
```

inside Matlab directory. I found there file "yy.cpp" which contains `mexFunction` which does the thing. Very likely that Matlab calls this function to simulate network.

Seems that it's possible to integrate this function into your project after slight refactoring. At least I plan to do so. :-)