# Use a neural network generated by MATLAB in C++

Tags: neural-network, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have generated a network with MATLAB.
I can see the result of this network for my inputs in MATLAB via this command:

```
sim(net, 0.01)
```

I want to do this work in C++ with the "net" generated by MATLAB.
How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [matlab neural network toolbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192165/matlab-neural-network-toolbox)

Comment: Also see: [Is it possible to compile MATLAB files that call Neural Network Toolbox functions into stand-alone applications?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-19HN4/index.html?product=NN), and [Neural Networks Functions Convert to C++ codes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/32980-neural-networks-functions-convert-to-c-codes)

Comment: C/C++ Perceptron: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccperceptron/

Answer (score 1):

If you can generate a Simulink model of the network then you can export your network to the C language (like *[Exporting Neural Network to C++](http://compgroups.net/comp.soft-sys.matlab/exporting-neural-network-to-c++/408091)*), it's simple. But I do not think this method will be good to use a neural network for other programs.

To me the better solution is to use of the neural network formula (like in *[Try to simulate a neural network in MATLAB by myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739684/try-to-simulate-a-neural-network-in-matlab-by-myself)*) and use of weights of network that exports from trained network in MATLAB be used in your own program, because it's easy and clean.